# How to SUM the value from DISTINCT row using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Datatable as below:

```
Item CartonID Quantity
A    0001     1000
A    0002     500
A    0003     250
A    0002     500
B    0002     500
B    0003     250
```

My output suppose to be this:

```
ItemNo CartonID        TotalCarton TotalQuantity
A      0001,0002,0003  3           2250
B      0002,0003       2           750
```

But my result is list as below:

```
ItemNo  CartonID            TotalCarton  TotalQuantity
    A   0001, 0002, 0003    3              2,250
    B   0002, 0003          2                750
```

My code is list as below:

```
var items = ( from item in dtTest.AsEnumerable()
              group item by new
              {
                  Item_No=item.Field<string>("Item")
              }
              into g
              select new
              {
                  g.Key.Item_No,
                  TotalCarton = (from p in dtTest.AsEnumerable()
                                 where p.Field<string>("Item") == g.Key.Item_No
                                 select p.Field<string>("CartonID")).Distinct().ToArray().Count(),
                  Total_Quantity =g.Sum((p=>p.Field<decimal>("Quantity"))).ToString("###,###,###,###"),
                  CartonID = (from p in dtTest.AsEnumerable()
                              where p.Field<string>("Item") == g.Key.Item_No
                              select p.Field<string>("CartonID")).Distinct().ToArray().Aggregate
                              ((p1, p2) => p1 + ", " + p2)
                 }).ToList();
```

Anyone can tell me how to sum the total with distinct Carton ID. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you have a total carton of 4 for Item B?

Comment: What does TotalCarton represent?  Why, in your example, should the TotalCarton for item B be four instead of two?  With your data, for Item A, there are four cartons, but three of theme are distinct (TotalCarton = 3).  For Item B, there are only two cartons (TOtalCarton = 2).

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault. The total carton for Item B is 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should GroupBy CartonID and then sum the groups elements:

something like this

```
dtTest.GroupBy(x => x.CartonId)
      .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Sum(z => z.Quantity);
```

This will return a dictionary containing the total quantity per each CartonID. I hope i understood correctly that this is what you want.

---

Based on the Output that you said is supposed to be retrieved, i adapted the query to this:

```
dtTest.GroupBy(x => x.ItemNo)
      .Select(itemGroup => new { 
              itemGroup.Key,
              itemGroup.Distinct(item => item.CartonID), 
              itemGroup.Distinct(item => item.CartonID).Count(),
              itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Quantity)
});
```

Comment: Hi @dutzu, I understand your idea. But how to make it work in VS2010 by C#? Currently I cannot GroupBy directly using dtTest.

Comment: The probably you need to cast dtTest to .AsEnumerable or something :)

Comment: I already try using dtTest.AsEnumerable() but there got other syntax error for the remaining code.

Comment: @Zero - The ideea is there, all you need to is to adapt the code to what you exactly have. I also made some changes to my code snippet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. I get the result. Thank you very much.